# Window properties becomes undefined

Tags: javascript

This is a very general question. Sadly I cannot provide you with any code sample that could help to shed some light on this particular issue.

I have quite a complex script that works with window objects (main window or window from iframes). I store them to variables and work with them later.

This script has an error logging mechanism. It tries to catch all possible errors ([unhandledrejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) and [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) events) and sends them via [beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) to the backend service.

It works just fine for most of the users but I can see sometimes these types of logs.

```
currentWindow.removeListener is not a function
element instanceof currentWindow.HTMLElement - the right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

`currentWindow` is just a variable I store when script loads. (`const currentWindow = window`). I am pretty sure the window object doesn't get altered from the user in any way and the window variable I store is not overwritten.

To me, it seems that window properties are getting cleared. I suspect it happens when the tab is (force) closed. I tried many things to replicate -- CPU throttling, force closing chrome etc.) I have literally no clue why it happens and cannot find any related info here or on google.

I should also note that it is not some issue with old browsers. It happens in the newest version of chrome as well as firefox.

Comment: Without code this question is not reproducible, so we can't really help you, i can just link you that mdn page maybe you can read and understand the problem. [TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand 'x'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/invalid_right_hand_side_instanceof_operand)

Comment: You don't get my question. I understand why it throws `instanceof` error.  The thing I haven't solved yet is why/when standard window properties get cleared.

Comment: Are you sure in some part of website the variable is empty/null or undefined?

Comment: When you log error you save which page have this problem?

Comment: I am pretty sure and after all, it's constant so it cannot get overwritten.  I store also URLs. It's my react application. Hence I am saying I am sure window object doesn't get altered by any external script.

Comment: You have tried `const currentWindow = window; console.log(currentWindow);` ?

Comment: Yep, maybe I shouldn't have mentioned that I store it to a variable because it may lead to false clues...

Comment: If the variable is recalled from several pages there could be some conflict, however I repeat you should see on which page the error is generated so as to begin to better understand in which portion of code to work.

Comment: `window` objects are getting cleared on closing or emptying. This also happens on `iframe` and unfinished scripts trying to refer to no more existing `window`. One test case that worked for me was starting a `setTimeout()` in an `iframe` and close / remove the `iframe` before callback or do the same with an ajax call.

Comment: @JavaScript do you have an example to share? I tried this but setTimeout callback is never executed. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wood-43u53?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Sadly I have no standalone example which I am able to provide right now. I work with `iframe` alot for one project and know it from experience. Especially since `window` properties like `XMLHttpRequest` are throwing errors on ajax callbacks due to the missing `window` on ancient browsers (.. yes banking systems are old).